# Installing a package into a virtual environment on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am used to programming on a Mac or a Linux box where installing packages into a virtual environment is relatively straightforward.  Unfortunately, that does not seem to be the case with Windows.   I have been trying to install lxml into a virtual environment on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

First I used pip (my preferred tool):

```
(lxml_tutorial) PS C:\Users\spearsc\Documents\python_projects\lxml_tutorial> pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_spearsc\lxml\setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ic:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_spearsc\lxml\src\lxml\includes -IC:\P
ython27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src\lxml\lxml.etree.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o -w
    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\spearsc\\ap
pdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_spearsc\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip-c22v0y-record\install-r
ecord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.

Building without Cython.

ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.



** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **



Using build configuration of libxslt

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\html

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron

copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml

copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\includes

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\
rng

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxm
l\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\i
soschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\
lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win
-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml
\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lxml\isoschematr
on\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\lxml

gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ic:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_spearsc\lxml\src\lxml\includes -IC:\Pytho
n27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src\lxml\lxml.etree.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o -w

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\spearsc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_b
uild_spearsc\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip-c22v0y-record\install-record.txt --single-versio
n-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\spearsc\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_spearsc\lxml
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\spearsc\pip\pip.log
```

I have seen this error before.  I think it is caused by the C compiler not being set.  I knew from past experience that fixing this issue is a tremendous pain, so I decided to try another method.

I went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and downloaded the exe file for lxml.  Then I activated my virtual environment and ran the executable in it.  The library was installed globally, which was not what I wanted, so I uninstalled lxml.

For my third attempt, I activated my virtual environment and used easy_install to install lxml.  Once again, the package was installed globally!  I uninstalled lxml with pip.

I am really disappointed.  Am I just going to have to install all my packages globally and forget about using virtual environments?  Most of the solutions I have seen on the web seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, when I use my virtual environment's `easy_install`, it installs only in that virtual env, not globally.

But that aside, another way to go about this is to create a wheel from the .exe, and `pip install` that. (Wheel/.whl is the new standard replacing the .egg format. See [PEP 427](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) or [readthedocs](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/), among others.)

Do the following:

- `pip install wheel`
- download the .exe
- `wininst2wheel.exe <downloaded .exe file>`
- `pip install <created .whl file>`

Comment: Got it to work!  The trick is to use the pip inside the virtual environment.  In order to create the .whl file, I used wininst2wheel.py.  I could not find wininst2wheel.exe.  Of course after all the hacking, I could have probably just copied the folders into the site-packages directory in my virtual environment.  My guess is that would have worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

After you have installed the lxml from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml, from `"C:/python/lib/site-packages"`, copy and paste the following files to your virtual environment "/lib/site-packages".

1. lxml(folder)
2. lxml-3.3.5-py2.7.egg-info(folder)